# Define a type to receive latitude and longitude in xml format

Tags: regex, xml

I have a command line interface, from which I can configure Latitude and Longitude of a particular device.

I need help for accepting these values as new type named LATITUDE and LONGITUDE.
So that I can omit the validation part from my source code. {Since Command line interface itself check the values, if there is type as LATITUDE and LONGITUDE}

Valid Range of Latitude is -90 to +90

Valid Range of Longitude is -180 to +180

**EDIT**

Ihave tried These regexes

Latitude RegEx:

```
@"^(\+|-)?((\d((\.)|\.\d{1,6})?)|(0*?[0-8]\d((\.)|\.\d{1,6})?)|(0*?90((\.)|\.0{1,6})?))$"
```

Longitude RegEx:

```
@"^(\+|-)?((\d((\.)|\.\d{1,6})?)|(0*?\d\d((\.)|\.\d{1,6})?)|(0*?1[0-7]\d((\.)|\.\d{1,6})?)|(0*?180((\.)|\.0{1,6})?))$"
```

Normal Regular expressions for Both latitude & longitude:

Latitude RegEx:

```
^(+|-)?((\d((.)|.\d{1,6})?)|(0*?[0-8]\d((.)|.\d{1,6})?)|(0*?90((.)|.0{1,6})?))$
```

Longitude RegEx:

```
^(+|-)?((\d((.)|.\d{1,6})?)|(0*?\d\d((.)|.\d{1,6})?)|(0*?1[0-7]\d((.)|.\d{1,6})?)|(0*?180((.)|.0{1,6})?))$
```

These regexes are not taking values correctly.

For ex: I want to give 24.45 but cli giving illegal parameter error

Comment: Its humble request to those who are down voted. Please Comment Your suggestions too. This question is based on my requirement. Not for making impression. Please do comment

Comment: Do you want `regex` for latitude and longitude range?

Comment: Thanks for asking I have made some edit here. I wanr RegEx for taking like 89.34, 120.74 etc

Comment: range of values after decimal can be from `0-99`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the digits after decimal can be from `0-99`, you can try this

**[Latitude](https://regex101.com/r/fN3zW8/3)**

```
^(-|\+)?(90|[0-8]?[0-9](\.[0-9]?[0-9])?)$
```

or

```
^(-|\+)?(90|[0-8]?\d(\.\d?\d)?)$
```

**[Longitude](https://regex101.com/r/oK8yM7/3)**

```
^(-|\+)?(180|([0-9]?|1[0-7])[0-9](\.[0-9]?[0-9])?)$
```

or

```
^(-|\+)?(180|(\d?|1[0-7])\d(\.\d?\d)?)$
```

Comment: The RegEx u r given above accepting values 91 92...etc are as valid values for latitude. how can i avoid that. because latitude max val is 90 and min val is -90

Comment: @runner please see the demo..its not accepting `91` or `92`. Maybe you are using regex of `longitude` instead of `latitude`. If there is problem please ask

Comment: @runner Tell if the problem persists

Comment: thnks for your concern. I made some edit and its working now

Comment: @runner Was there any edit required in regex?If yes can you tell the edit?

Comment: The changes are
    Longitude RegEx: "^(-|\+)?((180)|([0-1]?[0-7]?[0-9])|([0-1]?[0-7]?[0-9](\.[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]))?)$"

    Latitude RegEx: "^(-|\+)?((90)|([0-8]?[0-9])|([0-8]?[0-9](\.[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]))?)$"

Now its not taking any values beyond the Max and Min Values of Lat and Lon. I would never have found this without your help. Thanks for the help here, while others were busy with down voting my question.

Comment: @runner why the changes? my `regex` is working fine.. Can you please tell the case where it is failing after looking at demo here :- https://regex101.com/r/fN3zW8/3

Comment: @runner my regex is also looking ok..it is not accepting value above `MAX` and below `MIN`. I just want to know a case where its failing

Comment: Yes. your code woking fine. I tested with the link you gave. But I dont know why its not woking with my Klish parser.